# Windows 7 - File Sharing "Computername\Username"

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, samba

Is there a way to disable the computer name being added to the beginning of my username while using windows file sharing? It's really annoying since i'm trying to mount a samba share and it doesn't accept my name with "computername\" being added to it..

Comment: trying using just your name in the samba string, and specifying your domain as computername?...I wished I had Windows 7 to play with still.

Answer (score 0):

Typing \username will remove the computer name from the beginning of the user name.

However, having found this, I still wasn't able to connect to my Samba shares...